# Recovery mode. Terminal

Tags: консоль, recovery

В терминале в режиме Recovery mode, проверял работает ли терминал. Для этого выполнил команду:
ls ~
, после чего увидел далеко не содержимое своей папки. Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: Дык в режиме восстановления пользователь `root` небось.  И увидели вы скорее всего содержимое `/root`.

Comment: Какой пользователь в recovery mode логинится, та домашняя папка и отображается. А логинится скорее всего вышеупомянутый root, ведь это ж recovery

Comment: Непонятно мне что то

Comment: Как мне начать видеть свою папку?